# エミュレータがフリーズするようになった

Tags: android, android-studio

普段Android Studio付属のSDKのエミュレータを使用しています。
メインで使用しているNexus 5のエミュレータがフリーズするようになりました。
スペックは以下です。

- 機種: Nexus 5
- OS: Android 5.1.1 x86
- Emulated Preformance: Use Host GPU
- RAM: 1536 MB
- VM heap: 64 MB
- Internal Storage: 200 MB
- SD card: Studio-managed 100 MB

このエミュレータには開発中のアプリやテスト用のアプリを入れています。
フリーズするようになったのは確か数日前GPU オーバードローを試したままエミュレータを終了させてからで、フリーズするタイミングは主に以下の3つです。

- ロック画面
- ロック解除後
- アプリ操作中

最近はフリーズするまでの時間が延びているような気もします。
改めてGPU オーバードローをオンにしてオフにするというのをやってみましたが、効果はなさそうでした。

フリーズ中にテストを実行させてみると、UIに関係しないテストは通り、UIが関係するテストは以下のようなActivityを起動し忘れたのでは？的なエラーメッセージが表示されました。

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: No activities in stage RESUMED. Did you forget to launch the activity. (test.getActivity() or similar)?
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
以下略
```

UIに関係しないテストがどのように実行されるかわかりませんが、
完全にフリーズしているわけではないのかもしれません。

現在は代わりに他を使うようにしていたりしますが、
もしこのエミュレータがフリーズする原因の見当がつく方がいたら教えて欲しいです。

Answer (score -1):

できるかわかりませんが、原因と思われるものを見つけたので答えておきます
[Emulator(AVD)がCrashする問題](http://qiita.com/toris-birds/items/55ddad8b0f81365cd510) 
の資料2のところにあります。

GLAsyncSwapをデフォルトで無効にすることによって、一部のGPU構成で発生するクラッシュを修正しました。この機能は25.3.0で追加され、ゲームやビデオのフレームタイミングとフレーム/秒を改善しましたが、未知のマシン構成ではエミュレータが動作しなくなりました。手動で有効にするには、android_sdk / emulator / lib / advancedFeatures.iniファイルを開き、GLAsyncSwap = onを設定します。